# python用scipyがraspberry piにダウンロードできません

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pip, scipy

ラスベリーパイでPythonのプログラムを書いています。デジタル信号処理をやりたいのでscipyをダウウンロードしたいのですがうまくいきません。
コマンドラインから以下のコマンドでダウンロードしようとしました。

```
＄python -m pip install scipy --user
```

ところが以下のエラーが出ます。`pip list` を見てもscipyがありません。
scipyをダウンロードするにはどうしたらいいでしょうか。

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-installmEb21z/scipy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n','\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-5cX2pH/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user 
--prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-mEb21z/scipy/

Failed cleaning build dir for scipy

Failed building wheel for scipy
```

Comment: OSは何でしょう？ Ubuntu？それとも Raspberry Pi OS？ あとたぶん Python**3** だろうと思うけど, それをデフォルトにしてるかどうかの情報も必要です

Comment: scipy パッケージをビルドするのに必要な BLAS/LAPACK や gcc, gfortran がインストールされていないのではないかと思います(その他、諸々のパッケージが必要です)。なので、[ここ](https://www.piwheels.org/simple/scipy/)から scipy の wheel ファイルをダウンロードしてインストールしてみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: raspbianです

Comment: `python --version` あるいは `python`とターミナルで入力するとバージョン分かります。何も設定してなければ `python3` コマンドを実行しない限り `python2`が動くような？

Comment: どの OSを使っていてバージョンが何で(64 or 32bitなども), Pythonのどのバージョン…などの動作環境を質問の中に含めたほうがよいでしょう。
問題が起きてることは分かるけど, (Pythonは)何を動かしてるのかさえ不明です。
質問にあたってhttps://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking
良い質問をするには？https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
などのガイドがあります。